# Pasing a value from Controller to Custom Action Atribute Filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, custom-action-filter

I have a controller which inherits from a **BaseController** class. This **BaseController** has a **protected** property *currentUser* which is of type **myUser**.

I have  created a "Custom Action Filter Attribute" and I need to access the value of **myUser** within this atrtribute's **OnActionExecuting()** event.

Is this possible? If so, how can I implement this feature?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it but first you have convert your currentUser property from **protected** to **public** or expose it through read only property or method.

Then you can access it using the following

```
var baseController = filterContext.Controller as BaseController;
if (baseController != null) {
    //Access your exposed **public** property or method
    baseController.currentUser 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to overide the OnActionExecuting method which will have an 'ActionExecutingContext' object passed in.

That object has a property Controller, which is the current controller. You can check if that is of the desired type.

So:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
  MyUser currentUser = null;

  var controller = filterContext.Controller as BaseController;
  if (controller != null) {
     currentUser = controller.CurrentUser;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a bit change to change the accessor of myUser from protected to public is required but it works well. Thank you very much.

Comment: ah, yes, I missed the bold 'protected' in your question.... It might be time for some reading glasses